# Mixed content issue- Content must be served as HTTPS || Lumen || Swagger API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, lumen-5.2

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://api.xyz.com/api/documentation' was loaded over HTTPS,

but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://api.xyz.com/swagger-ui-assets/swagger-ui.css?v=26ec363936a21921c9fec290e551e3eb'.

This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I know how to solve this problem in Laravel but unable to solve this in case of Lumen.

Tried Solutions:

1. Added below line in AppServiceProvider

   ```
   URL::forceSchema('https');
   ```

Comment: try removing the http from the stylesheet's url and jut leave a single /

Comment: How are you loading the stylesheet ?

Comment: @Mike I am using Swagger for API documentation. and it is working fine over HTTP but over HTTPS it is not working.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @RadheShyamsharma? Still getting problems with this.

Answer (score 3):

update `boot()` method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file as bellow

```
public function boot()
{
    if(env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
       URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

alse update APP_ENV to `APP_ENV=prod` in `.evn` file

Comment: thanks it is wokring

Answer (score 0):

Check the `APP_URL` in the .env file which is set to `http://localhost`

Heroku uses `https://appname.herokuapp.com` since it's in production but lumen uses `http://localhost` for dev mode so I fixed it by running `heroku config:set APP_URL=https://localhost`